# Why there is a increase in data size after migration of Cassandra to Cosmos?

Tags: azure, cassandra, azure-storage, azure-cosmosdb

We successfully migrated around 3 GB of data from Cassandra to Cosmos. And  observered around ~5 times increase in data size (Same data; no additional rows are yet added)

While I hear from others that this is as expected,

1. Why is this data size increase for the same data ? Cassandra maintains a low profile for the same data but Cosmos bloats it.
2. Are there any tools to validate if all the data has been successfully migrated ?

Comment: Was the provided answer helpful to you? If so please mark it as an answer for visibility to help the community.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Cosmos DB can automatically scale storage and throughput as your requirements grow. You can estimate your throughput needs by using the Azure [**Cosmos DB request unit calculator**](https://www.documentdb.com/capacityplanner) If you use this planner this should give you an idea about the ratio of data storage that's going to be used.

Another factor is the use of : **[Horizontal Partitioning/Scaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data)**, this possibly could be the main factor that caused the increase of your data size. I'd recommend re-partitioning(documents include links on how to as well.). to monitor if this is the cause, you can use the **[monitoring of your partitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/use-metrics)**:

*To determine the storage distribution of any partitioned container broken down by partitions, head to the Metrics blade in the Azure portal. In the Storage tab, the storage breakdown is shown in the Data + Index storage consumed by top partition keys chart.*

For any other questions, feel free to contact the Cosmos DB team : askcosmosdb[at]microsoft.com

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. In addition to the above answer, can you let me know if replicator factor can also increase the size of the data ?

Comment: Also, how do I check the total number of replication factor's here ? (I'm not talking abt the geo replication factor but the local replication factors here)